# Select all values in Multi Select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select all selected, Non selected value in multiple select box using jquery. How to do this. Can anyone help me on this.

```
$("#rSelectedBrand").val()
```

This command selects only selected value in multiple select box but I want non selected value also in the array.

Thanks

Comment: Post related code please.

Comment: Do you want to literally get all values into one array, or have one array of selected values and another of non-selected values?

Comment: @JamieBarker I want to select all in one array

Comment: @AlexChar Question updated

Answer (score 0):

you can use this plugin for multiselect.

it's wonderful.

```
$(function(){
   $("select").multiselect(); 
});
```

http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#animations

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @antyrat okay,
thanks for advice,
i will take from next time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery [**.map()**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) and create an array with all values like:

```js
console.log($("select option").map(function() {
      return this.value;
    }).get());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple">
  <option>1</option>
  <option selected>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option selected>4</option>
</select>
```

**References**

[.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/)